# Calling .close on AndroidHttpClient crashes when using ssl

Tags: android

I'm using AndroidHttpClient to make a https post request to a login page. The client instance is created like this:

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
```

After making the request to https://mydomain.com/login my activity crashes when later calling client.close().

The connection returns a valid response and when not using ssl on the same domain (http://mydomain.com/login) everything works fine, i can call client.close() with no crash.

I haven't looked at the source code but Android's documentation on this is very brief, just saying .close should be called to release resources associated with the client. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something else? Is there a better way to close/release resources for this type of object?

Comment: Please check if the logcat says something about the crash. If so, post the logcat.

Comment: Sorry, exception was: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I'm calling client.close() in onPostExecute of an asyncTask which should still not be in the main thread though I think

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, `onPostExecute` is called on the UI thread. If this doesn't help, please post more of your code. Make it an SSCCE if your code is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your NetworkOnMainThreadException:
The three methods onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are executed on the UI thread. That's one of the main points of AsyncTasks.
So, move your `close()` call to `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guess this was sort of a dumb question, and was related to calling client.close() in onPostExecute which I guess does execute in main thread? Moving it into the doInBackground method fixed the problem.